# Is there a way in Typescript to make a namespace global?

Tags: typescript

I have an Input module that needs to be accessible globally, is it possible to make the import a bit cleaner. Currently, I would have to import it like this `import { Input } from "./Input/Input";` Is there a way to not have to define the path for modules that have an abstract class? So it would look more like this `import { Input } from "Input";` no matter where the module is in the project? Or maybe not even an import at all?

```
import { KeyboardInput } from "./KeyboardInput";
import { TouchInput } from "./TouchInput";
import { MouseInput } from "./MouseInput";

abstract class Input {
    static keyboard: KeyboardInput;
    static touchInput: TouchInput;
    static mouseInput: MouseInput;

    static initialize() {
        Input.keyboard = new KeyboardInput();
        Input.touchInput = new TouchInput();
        Input.mouseInput = new MouseInput();
    }
}

export { Input };
```

Comment: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/10/07/absolute-paths-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would be a nightmare to find where that file is coming from if you haven't specified the path correctly. And having it be imported even without an `import` would be even worse. The "clean" way of importing is the way you are currently doing it.